# Why can't I connect to Active Directory Users and Computers from Windows 7, but can from XP?

Tags: active-directory

I am able to connect to the domain controller using the Active Directory Users and Computers mmc while logged in to a Windows XP or Windows Server 2003 computer, but get an Access Denied error when trying to connect to the same server while on any Windows 7.

The 2 other IT workers have the same issue. Each of us have no problem while on XP, just Windows 7, regardless of which Windows 7 computer it is (as we have tried multiple machines).

Comment: Are the windows 7 machines actually on the domain, with the right product of windows?

Comment: Yes these Windows 7 machines are located on the domain, as are the admin accounts used to connect to the domain controllers. Each account works on a Windows XP machine, but not Windows 7. "Access denied".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discovered the problem was that our accounts belonged to too many Active Directory groups and the Kerberos token size. 
A registry key needed to be created to increase the Kerberos fixed token size limit from 12000 to 65535.

This [Technet forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/9ff3d362-883a-457c-910a-406a13d438f9/) discusses the problem and this [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263693) details the fix.

Registry fix required:

1. Start Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe)
2. Locate and click the following key in the registry
   **System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters**
3. If this key is not present, create the key. To do so:
   a. Click the following key in the registry:
      **System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos**
   b. On the Edit menu, click Add Key
   c. Create a Parameters key
   d. Click the new Parameters key
4. On the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following registry value
   Value name: **MaxTokenSize**
   Data type: **REG_DWORD**
   Radix: **Decimal**
   Value data: **65535**
5. Quit Registry Editor